# How to delete elements from array from certain value on?

Tags: php

I have an array in PHP and I don't know how to delete all the elements from every array element from certain character on, icluding that character. Is there a way to do this?

```php
array(1092) {
  ["Piper;Rosii;Sare;Test;Vinete#####Piper ->Negru;Rosii ->Călite;Sare ->De masă, grunjoasă;Vinete ->Prăjite"]=>
  int(124)
}
```

In my example I want to delete all text from "#####", including "#####" to the end, foreach array element. Is this possible? Or is there a PHP function for this?

UPDATE

My result should look like this:

```php
array(1092) {
  ["Piper;Rosii;Sare;Test;Vinete]=>
  int(124)
}
```

Comment: I think you made a little mistake with creating your array, regarding the key value ..

Comment: What do you mean? I want that key because it's a count. Long story. All i need is a way to delete from every array element the content from this point on '######'. Is there a PHP function for that?

Comment: Update your question and show us what you want the end results to look like.

Comment: And can you show the code where you create the array?

Comment: @Fluinc, I've updated my question with that. It helps?

Comment: @lonut Yes please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk` to apply the `substr` and `strpos` to each element:

```
$array = [
    '23845637;54634;345;3453345;#####morestuff',
    '234234#####34596078345j34534534',
    '34343245dfg#####asdfsadf;23452345;sdfsdf;345345'
];

array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '#####'));
});

var_dump($array);
```

Will result in:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "23845637;54634;345;3453345;"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "234234"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "34343245dfg"
}
```

This will modify the original array.

For each element in the array, we search for the position of '#####' in the string and only take the part from 0 to the position in the string where '#####' occurs.

Comment: What they wanted to change was the was the key not the value.

Answer (score 1):

This will do that by looping through the array exploding the key by ##### and adding it to a new array. I did it in a loop in case your array is bigger than 1

```
<?php
$oldArray = array("Piper;Rosii;Sare;Test;Vinete#####Piper ->Negru;Rosii ->Călite;Sare ->De masă, grunjoasă;Vinete ->Prăjite" => 124);
$newArray = array();

foreach ($oldArray as $key => $row) {
    $newKey = explode('#####', $key);
    $newArray[$newKey[0]] = $row;
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` and `strpos` to add the new entry and then `unset` the old entry in the array like this example:

```
$array = array(
    "Piper;Rosii;Sare;Test;Vinete#####Piper ->Negru;Rosii ->Călite;Sare ->De masă, grunjoasă;Vinete ->Prăjite" => 124
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '#####'))] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Will result in:

```
array(1) {
  ["Piper;Rosii;Sare;Test;Vinete"]=>
  int(124)
}
```